# Increase price of all products after every sale (WOOCOMMERCE)

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I would like to increase the price by $20 of all products after every new sell in woocommerce

Exemple:

- Starting prices $50
- First order : all products prices become $70
- Second order : all products prices become $90
- Third : all products prices become $110

and so...

Answer (score 0):

I believe this plugin should give you what you want it is a bit outdated so use at your own caution

https://wordpress.org/plugins/raise-prices-with-sales-for-woocommerce/

Comment: Thanks a lot bro; it's not exactly what i was searching for. But i started from it to build a custom function with my custom needs